# How to display the number of 'missing' hours in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I know this kind of tricky but what I am trying to find is the number of missing values (not SHOWN at all (instead of null)) based on TABLE1.code, TABLE1.HOUR, TABLE2.DATA_TYPE, TABLE3.FILE_NAME. Aside from when DST changes in the fall and spring, we always expect 24 hours for each day.

So I have a following columns in my table (TABLE1): VALUE_ID, VALUE, HOUR, CODE, DAY_OF_YEAR

```
 VALUE_ID      VALUE     HOUR                  CODE      DAY_OF_YEAR     
   1             7       1-1-2018 01:00 AM      HI        0012018
   2             9       1-1-2018 03:00 AM      HI        0012018
   3             22      1-1-2018 04:00 AM      HI        0012018
   4             55      1-1-2018 05:00 AM      HI        0012018
   5             99      1-1-2018 06:00 AM      HI        0012018
   6             77      1-1-2018 07:00 AM      HI        0012018
   7             33      1-1-2018 08:00 AM      HI        0012018
```

I have the following columns in my second table (TABLE2): VALUE_ID, FILE_ID, DATA_TYPE

```
VALUE_ID          FILE_ID             DATA_TYPE
  1                  1                 REG
  2                  1                 REG
  3                  1                 IRREG
  4                  1                 IRREG
  5                  1                 AB
  6                  1                 AB
  7                  1                 AB
```

I have the following column in my third table (TABLE3): FILE_ID, File_Name, FILE_DATE

```
 FILE_ID             FILE_NAME            FILE_DATE
    1               samplefile.csv        10-19-2018
```

Below is the expected outcome:

```
 FILE_NAME        DATA_TYPE       CODE      TRUNC(HR)     MissingValues#
 samplefile.csv   REG             HI        1-1-2018        22
 samplefile.csv   IRREG           HI        1-1-2018        22
 sameplfile.csv   AB              HI        1-1-2018        21
```

**Objective:** based on which days and files we have submitted for those days, we need to find the number of values that weren't submitted for that day for that certain data_type and code.

Comment: What if a datatype "CD" was expected, but was not in the file, or what if no file was sent for a certain date?

Comment: What is the expected effect of a value_id that is present in table2 but not in table1, like in your example is the case for 6 and 7?

Comment: I don't understand what makes a value "missing"? Can you explain more about where the 22, 22, and 21 MissingValues# comes from, please? Also, does it matter that the rows for value_ids 6 and 7 aren't present in table1?

Comment: What if for the same file and same data type the day of the year is different?

Comment: Also, how are you supposed to know what the code is supposed to be for those value_ids in table2 that aren't present in table1 ? I.e. in your example, if the missing value # is `24 - <number of rows present for that hour date, e.g. 1/1/2018>`, for AB, you actually have two codes - HI and <NULL>. If there were multiple codes in table1 for the same file_id and AB value_ids in table2, which code do the missing table1 value_id rows belong to?

Comment: It sounds like you have code that peers into the contents of the CSV and compares against the data in tables 1 and 2 to make some decisions about what is missing. If so, it would help us to help *you* if you would share that existing code and the contents of `sameplfile.csv`. And, as @Boneist said, provide a more detailed definition of what  you mean by *missing*.

Comment: @StoneGiant I actually don't have code that peers into the contents of the CSV, we work with whatever data we have in the tables.

Comment: Okay, wow. I'm really confused then. I'll move along and let smarter people handle this. My apologies.

Comment: @Boneist I am assuming there are 24 hours in each day except for DST / NON-DST switching days. we are assuming all codes (present in the sample) apply for all file types, value_ids, files, etc.

Comment: @Boneist Since there are only 2 hours worth of data when data_type = REG, CODE = HI and File_Date = 1/1/2018 (a non-DST switching day) , we are assuming the other 22 hours are missing. (2 AM and 4AM-11PM)

Comment: @StoneGiant , sorry is my question really badly worded?

Comment: @JohnWick my question is around value_ids 6 and 7 - they don’t have a row in table1, so how do you know which table1.code they are supposed to match to?

Comment: @Boneist, sorry yeah I must have forgot to add those 2 rows, ive edited my question :)

Comment: In which case, join your tables, and find the count of rows present or trunc(hr). Then the missing row count is 24 - count(*)... (That’s assuming one row per hour per value_id in table1, of course)

Comment: The question itself is clear. We can easily see that for REG there are only two entries for 2018-01-01 for instance, so 22 are missing. But we don't know, if they existed, what code they would have. It could be anything. We also don't know which file they would refer to. Could be any file again. So your results should not contain code and file name.

Comment: @Boneist what about on DST days (23 hours) or DST ending days (25 hours)?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, we can tie back the values to the FILE_ID. We can assume the data_codes that are all present in the sample data ( at least in this case)

Comment: Do multiple days exist in one file?

Comment: @Hartco no, just one day

Comment: That’s for you to work out!  You haven’t provided any data for that situation. If possible, try and get the dates as non-daylight saving either instead of or as well as. That would solve your problem.

Comment: @Boneist would you be able to show me an example of what you explained please ? :)

Comment: @JohnWick not until Monday now, sorry. But if you had the date in daylight savings and non-daylight savings (eg. UTC + 1 and UTC, you could use the UTC to work from and the UTC + 1 to display.

Comment: I don't see what we can assume actually. Let's say the three rows 5, 6, and 7 have different codes HI, HO, HU in the first table and different file IDs 1, 2, and 3 in the second. What do you assume would be the codes and files for the missing hours? Why would you assume these values?

Comment: @Boneist no worries I am in no rush! i'll be pondering this over the weekend, haha.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner we can assume every possible combination for those 3 categories (so each file, we will expect every combination of 5, 6, 7 and HI, HO, HU = 9 total variations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what you say in the comments we can expect one record per hour, code, data_type, and file_name. So we cross join code, data_type, and file_name and check how many entries (i.e. hours) we actually find for the combination.

You find out how many hours a day has by subtracting the day's midnight from the following day's midnight and using local timestamps for this, i.e. considering the time zone.

```
select
  t3.file_name, t2.data_type, t1.code, days.day,
  ( -- 23, 24, or 25 hours
   (to_timestamp_tz(to_char(days.day + 1, 'yyyymmdd'), 'yyyymmdd') -
    to_timestamp_tz(to_char(days.day, 'yyyymmdd'), 'yyyymmdd')) * 24
  ) -
  (
    select count(*)
    from table1 tx1
    join table2 tx2 using (value_id)
    join table3 tx3 using (file_id)
    where tx3.file_name  = t3.file_name
      and tx2.data_type  = t2.data_type
      and tx1.code       = t1.code
      and trunc(tx1.hour) = days.day
  ) as missing_values
from (select distinct trunc(hour) as day from table1) days
cross join (select distinct code from table1) t1
cross join (select distinct data_type from table2) t2
cross join (select distinct file_name from table3) t3;
```

This query includes combinations that have no missing hours (missing_values = 0). You can of course enclose above query in a main query and dismiss those rows:

```
select * from ( above query ) where missing_values > 0;
```

Comment: THANK YOU so MUCH! Absolute Lifesaver, sorry for the headache.